# Vertexes, edges and faces not lighting up when selecting

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces, edges

I am new to blender.

I am following the chair tutorial from the blender Guru. Only my vertices, edges and faces are not lighting up anymore when selected. So I cant see what I am selecting. Selecting it self works though cause I can perform fill oparations to make faces between vertices.

I think the file should be possible to access with link below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Firstly you should add an image of your screen into your question. In Blender go to Window > Save Screenshot and save the image to, for instance, your desktop. Then edit your question here and you can insert that image using the image icon at the top of the editor or simply dragging and dropping it from your desktop into the editor. To upload your Blend file, follow the instructions [here](https://blend-exchange.com/help) exactly.

Comment: Thanks! The picture and file should be available now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have turned off the [Viewport Overlays](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html), as you can see in your screenshot. Have a look at the top right corner of the viewport. There is an icon with two circles, one is filled. The overlays display the axis, the floor grid, the name of the selected object, statistic text, **the selection outline**, and much other information.

Click this icon to activate the *Viewport Overlays*. In the drop-down menu to the right of it, you will find the options. In the menu you can choose what you want to see and what should be hidden.

[image: Viewport overlays icon]
(Borrowed screenshot of an older Blender version)